# Magento 2 attribute search product results

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I have a multi-select attribute with n number of options. I have assigned some options for the products. For example, I have an attribute color and have options like blue, red, green, and yellow assigned these options to products. I need these products in search results if someone searches for a color like yellow or green.

Comment: Ramesh KR did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Set your attribute as used in search **by selecting the attribute in the admin panel -> Storefront properties -> Use in Search = yes**